# What is multi-step time series forecasting?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

> Disclaimer: New to this field

I am researching ways to forecast a given time-series.

So, I understand what `Univariate` and `Multivariate` forecasting is. While going through different results, I came across `multistep time-series forecasting`([link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-step-time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-networks-python/)) and ways to do that.

My assumption: Whenever you forecast multiple times in a series, its called multi-step. Is this the definition or something much more detailed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, regarding your example. The author forecasts one(t), two(t+1) and three month (t+2) in advance, so he called it multi-step. It is to be expected that the near periods are easier to predict.

There are different possiblilities to do that:

First you could just use your training data to forecast all three time steps, like the author does.

Second, you could forecast the the value for t and then use that new "data" for your prediction in t+1 etc...This might improve your prognosis.

Answer (score 0):

In [TensorFlow forecasting tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#multi-step_dense), they call **multi-step dense** when the input window includes multiple time steps which got me confused. However, what I have seen overall that the model is **single-step** if we only forecast **one time unit**, it is **multi-step** if we forecast **more than one time units**. Hence, it is independent from the input.